# FM Radio with HifiBerry Amp2

Tags: gpio, audio, radio, hifiberry

Is there a way of running a Raspberry Pi 3 with a mounted [HifiBerry Amp2](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/hifiberry-amp2/) together with an FM Radio Module e.g. [TEA5767 FM Radio Breakout Board](https://www.instructables.com/id/TEA5767-FM-Radio-Breakout-Board-for-Arduino/)?

Currently I set up my RPI to run [Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) and Spotify Connect but sometimes my internet connection is really bad so I'd like to receive good old radio stations via FM.

I'm wondering since the HifiBerry Amp2 does not have a dedicated (or at least I'm not aware of it) "audio-in" port. In my humble understanding it just amplifies the audio signal from the RPI coming somehow through the GPIO pins.

Most Radio FM Modules obviously output their audio through some pins which I somehow would need to connect to the Hifiberry Amp2. Does anyone can point me in a direction of how to implement this?